# How we can add a span to a text inside ul, that is outside of li in jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css

how can i add a span to 'Test content1' and 'Test content2' ?

```
<ul>
    Test content1
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    Test content2
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't. That would be invalid.

Comment: Its possible, lets wait others will find

Comment: Short Answer: You shouldn't. The only acceptable child of a `<ul>` tag is a `<li>` tag. Anything else would be invalid HTML. It is possible, but it would not produce the results you want.

Comment: @user2962526 Why do you think you need to use a `span` rather than a `li`?

Comment: @user2962526 : killing kittens is a possibility too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only valid child element of a `<ul>` element is an `<li>` element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Usage_context), [HTML5 Spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), [HTML4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#edef-UL)).  So, it would not be valid to have text node children of a `<ul>` in the first place, and would also be invalid to have `<span>` children of a `<ul>`.  To do so, would have unpredictable results in different browsers.

But, if you just want to know how to wrap all the text node children of some given element in spans with jQuery:

```
$("#parent").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap("<span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put `<span>` inside the Test Content1 and Test Content2 why not put it inside the `<li>` and put `<span>` on it.

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Test content1</span></li>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li><span>Test content2</span></li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @greg0ire said, it is invalid. However you can provide a nested list like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Test content1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 1.1</li>
      <li>list item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Test content2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2.1</li>
      <li>list item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is a littler verbose; but it's readable. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use lh to add headers within the ul if thats what you are trying to do.

```
<ul>
     <lh>Test Content1</lh>
     <li>Item A</li>
     <li>Item B</li>
     <li>Item C</li>
     <lh>Test Content2</lh>
     <li>Item A</li>
     <li>Item B</li>
     <li>Item C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<lh>` hasn't been in any spec since [HTML 3.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/listheader.html).  It was dropped from the HTML 3.2 spec in 1997.  Don't use `<lh>`.